# expected "INDEX, ,, )"; SQL statement: ERROR with h2 as MODE=postgreSQL

Tags: spring-boot, h2

While using  H2 in postgresql mode, I am unable to load data.sql with above error

basically getting error message  expected INDEX, ,, );

Answer (score -1):

Issue was sytax error in sql create statement

there was missing bracket ")" at end of create statement query

create table foo (testdate date, card_uuid uuid, PRIMARY KEY (card_uuid); <- missing bracket here